# Applet php communication using POST

Tags: java, php, post, applet

so here is my problem. I simply can't get my applet&php communication going. I'm using the below class for communication

```
 import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.Vector;

public class POST {

   private String postParameters = "";
   private String webPage;
   private Vector<String>names;
   private Vector<String>values;

   public POST(){
      values = new Vector<String>();
      names = new Vector<String>();
   }

   /**
    * Adds a post variable (page.php?name=value)
    *
    * @param name the variable name
    * @param value the variable value, can be set to null, the url will simply become &name instead of &name=value
    * null
    */
   public void addPostValue(String name, String value) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
      if (value == null) {
         try {
            postParameters += "&" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8");
            names.add(name);
            values.add("");
         } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
         }
      } else {
         postParameters += "&" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8");
         names.add(name);
         values.add(value);
      }
   }

   /**
    * Send post data without waiting for site output
    *
    * @return true if sending data terminated succesfully
    */
   public boolean sendPost() {
      try {
         if (webPage == null || webPage.equals("")) {
            throw new Exception("Empty url");
         }
         URL url = new URL(webPage);
         URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
         conn.setDoOutput(true);
         OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
         wr.write(postParameters);
         wr.flush();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return false;
      }
      postParameters = "";
      return true;
   }

   /**
    * Sends data, then waits for site output
    *
    * @return null if no data is received, or a String containing the data
    */
   public String sendPostWithReturnValue() {

      String returnValue = "";
      try {
         if (webPage == null || webPage.equals("")) {
            throw new Exception("Empty url");
         }
         URL url = new URL(webPage);
         URLConnection conn =
                 url.openConnection();
         conn.setDoOutput(true);
         OutputStreamWriter wr =
                 new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
         wr.write(postParameters);
         wr.flush();
         BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
         String line;
         while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            returnValue += line + "\n";
         }
         wr.close();
         rd.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return null;
      }
      postParameters = "";
      values = null;
      names=null;
      values = new Vector<String>();
      names = new Vector<String>();
      return returnValue;
   }

   /**
    * Sets the page to point at for sending post variables
    *
    * @param webPageToPointAt the page that will receive your post data
    */
   public void setWebPageToPointAt(String webPageToPointAt) {
      webPage = webPageToPointAt;
   }

   /**
    * @returns A Nx2 matrix containing all parameters name and values
    */
   public String[][] getParameters() {
      String[][] str = new String[names.size()][2];
      for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
         str[i][0] = names.get(i);
         str[i][1] = values.get(i);
      }
      return str;
   }
}
```

And this is the function within my applet that is calling it

```
public void postajRezultat(int brojP, int brojH) throws IOException{
        P = Integer.toString(brojP);
        H = Integer.toString(brojH);


        POST post = new POST();
        post.addPostValue("brojH", H);
        post.addPostValue("brojP", P);
        post.addPostValue("ime", ime);

        post.setWebPageToPointAt(getCodeBase().toString() + "/includes/save.php");
        post.sendPost();
```

And last this is the simple php script that should show the results of POST. Please help me, I've tried everything and i won't work...The error php gives me is "Undefined index "ime", "brojP", "brojH".

```
<?php
            mysql_connect ("127.0.0.1","root","vertrigo");
            mysql_select_db ("projekt_db");
            $ime=$_POST['ime'];
            $brojP=$_POST['brojP'];
            $brojH=$_POST['brojH'];
            echo("Test");
            echo($brojP . "" . $ime . "" . $brojH);

            $a=mysql_query("INSERT INTO highscore ('id', 'ime', 'brojP', 'brojH') VALUES (NULL, '" . $ime . "'," . $brojP . "," . $brojH . ")");

        ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use some kind of framework for HTTP communication? 
In my experience Apache HTTP Client is excelent solution for such operations, it makes request very easy to implement eg.

```
 HttpPost post=new HttpPost("where_to_send_post_request_url")
 post.setEntity(createdURLEncodedEntity) // here you add your post parameters as entity
 response=client.execute(post); // execute your post
 String page=EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()); // get response as string content eg html
 EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity()); // release connection etc.
```

isn't that simple? You don't have to reinvent the wheel again:)